python pptx:how to insert picture on slide x
I have a program that creates a powerpoint presentation with a title slide and a number of slides that either have one picture/slide or 6 picture/slide. I have figured out how to create the presentation and the slides with 1 picture. I can also create the slide with 6 placeholders and insert the first picture. I am however stuck on how to later reference one of the slides with 5 remaining placeholders and insert the correct pictures as needed.
As of right now I have the a list of the slide with 5 placeholders remaining on them and can use a dictionary to tie the correct picture to the correct slide. i also have the pictures named such that I can tell which picture goes in which placeholder on the slide. I tired the following but got an error and can't figure out what I have done wrong.
activeslide=prs.slides.get(slidenun)

ipic_ph1=activeslide.placeholders[phid] #define picture place holder for individual side to go into 

iph_pic1=ipic_ph1.insert_picture(path+'/'+ip)

Where "slidenum" is the number of the slide where I want to place a picture, "phid" is the id of the place holder on the slide where I want the picture, and path+'/'+ip is the picture itself to be inserted. can anyone suggest why I am getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'placeholders'


The error is pretty clear. The activeslide is a NoneType. That means prs.slides.get(slidenun) returns None. That means there is no slide at position slidenun in prs.slides. Why? Well, we cannot know because of the lack of a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Guess: You have a typo and slidenun should be slidenum?

@ Axel Ritcher, although I ended up reconfiguring my program such that I dos not have to reference my slide by a slide number, you are definitely correct in catching that "slidenun" should have been 'slidenum'. when I reconfigured my code I left an old (nonworking) version and will report back if I go back and get it to work per suggestions (incase I need to use the method originally devised at a later date).
